# return value in Python

Tags: python, return, return-value

I would like my function to return 1, 2, or 3 values, in regard to the value of `bret` and `cret`.
How to do something more clever than this ? :

```
def myfunc (a, bret=False, cret=False):
  b=0
  c=0
  if bret and cret:
   return a,b,c
  elif bret and not cret:
   return a,b
  elif not bret and cret:
   return a,c
  else:
   return a
```

Comment: I'm not sure you want that. What if next question will be `how to handle tuples with different lengths`?

Comment: @alko Yup - especially for the two-form return where whether it's b or c is lost...

Comment: you are always returning a, a,0 or a,0,0

Comment: this is just an example @aro, in my real code `b` and `c` are more interesting values...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
def myfunc(a, bret=False, cret=False):
   ...
   return (a,) + ((b,) if bret else ()) + ((c,) if cret else ())
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def myfunc (a, bret=False, cret=False):
  b, c, ret = 0, 0, [a]
  if bret: ret.append(b)
  if cret: ret.append(c)
  return ret
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def myfunc(a, bret=False, cret=False):
    return [v for v, ret in [(a, True), (0, bret), (0, cret)] if ret]
```

Take a moment to read about [Python List Comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). They are handy very often!

Answer (score 1):

You might simply append your `return` values to a list or use `yield`.
You can iterate over the result afterwards and do what you please. 
Here's an explanation to the `yield`-Keyword: [What does the "yield" keyword do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained)

Answer (score 1):

You could return a list. Look:

```
def myfunc (a, bret=False, cret=False):

    list = []
    list.append(a)
    b=0
    c=0

    if bret:
        list.append(b)

    if cret:
        list.append(c)

    return list
```

Solve your question?

Comment: no, the problem is not having a list. The problem is that this won't work anymore if 3 conditions, then there would be 2^3=8 cases to distinguish ! not beautiful ;)

Comment: This is equivalent to a much earlier solution posted by @thefourtheye (and I'd recommend against calling the variable `list` since this shadows the built-in function.)

Answer (score 1):

Please note if you have to return tuple (in your question it returns tuple) use this -

```
def myfunc(a, bret=False, cret=False):
    return tuple([a] + [0 for i in (bret, cret) if i])
```

Comment: This returns `bret`/`cret` instead of `b`/`c`.

Comment: Return value is always - a, a,0 or a,0,0